# "Enable CORS" in AWS API Gateway resource?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-api-gateway, put

I have a problem with AWS API Gateway.
I'm developing a web application with Angular 4 (using TypeScript language), but if I invoke the PUT method from the frontend, 
the following error message appears:

```
Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

and it's very strange because in the AWS console the PUT method works perfectly (I did many tests directly from the API Gateway console with a stage after the deploy, and everything works well). If I go to "Actions/Enable CORS" all methods have the check, included the PUT method, and I don't explain exactly what is the problem with the API Gateway.

Why do I get this error if it seems all ok in API gateway? Is there a way to change these CORS?

Comment: Can you also please the requesting url, response headers of OPTIONS and PUT responding url to the ticket ?  You can use Postman or CURL if you cannot get it from browser.

Comment: That is not an error from API Gateway, it looks like whatever browser/client you're using is not allowing PUT

Answer (score 1):

What I recall when being smacked by this same problem a while ago...

When using a Lambda or HTTP proxy integration, you need to specify at a minimum the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header the in your lambda's response. You may have specify additional (don't have any code handy at the moment). I do recall this message to be somewhat misleading, and that testing from the management console works because it's not really using CORS because of how the console executes the tests.

Have a look at the last section in: [Enabling CORS for a REST API resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

You need to replace `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the host name used by your client app. As a quick test use `*`, but don't go to production as that defeats the purpose of CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your authorizer's `Token Source` to the `AllowHeaders`.

Click on Enable CORS, then add the `Token Source` to the end of `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

```
AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Amz-Date, X-Api-Key, X-Amz-Security-Token, {your Token Source}'"
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below steps,

1. Create a new OPTIONS method under the /services resource
2. Create and populate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin/Method/Headers in the OPTIONS method.

Enable CORS like below after create OPTIONS

[image]

Source :- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=644489

Comment: Enable CORS  is ALWAYS open from the root and can not be used with one of the methods!

Comment: I have edited answer a bit. If you don't have OPTIONS please add it. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: My OPTION method exists and already has Access-Control-Allow-Origin / Method / Headers. The application gives the same error...

Comment: did it sort out?